# I need horizontal scrolling for GridView

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've got my GridView inside another Panel and I got scrollbars but GridView is to big even with paging. So user needs to scroll down to scroll horizontal (to see horizontal scrollbar).

How can I add any horizontal scrolling trick for my GridView in the Panel. Maybe something from javascript ? My js knowledges is still being poor.

I really hard thinking on what that could be, maybe floating horizontal scrollbar ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the **CSS Overflow property**, see: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp

You may be able to add this to your asp Control, or see how the `<asp:Panel>` is rendered (I haven't used WebForms for a while, but I think it's a HTML `<span>`) and give it an appropriate element Id/class and set the CSS property in a seperate stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you but I already have scrollbars, but horizontal scroll is to far. So I need something near to use ...

Comment: Ahhh, I misunderstood. Could you resize the height of the Panel to allow the scrollbars to be visible on the same page height, or not needed, or change the overflow property so they're not needed? It's best not to change default behaviour of browser elements like scrollbars.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are searching for? :
[scrollLeft](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/)